# Getting issue as "SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 40" in while unit testing using mocha and chai

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am new to unit testing using Mocha and Chai. I am getting issue when I am testing my Rest API using  Mocha and Chai.

test.js

```
let  chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let chai = require('chai');
let should = chai.should ();
let expect = chai.expect;
let server = require('../app');
chai.use(chaiHttp)

describe("Put /api/approvedUser/:id",() => {
  it('it should Put the tasks ', (done) => {
                 const userid = 'farmer.Ak';
                  var userdata = {
                    ROLEID: 1,
                    approved: true 
                   }

                chai.request(server)
                    .put("/approvedUser/" + userid)
                    .send(userdata)
                    .end((err, res) => {
                        const body = res.body;
                        console.log(body);
                        res.should.have.httpstatus(200);                        
                        // res.body.should.be.a('object');
                         res.body.should.be.property('secret');
                        // res.body.should.be.property('ROLEID');
                        // res.body.should.be.property('approved');
                        // res.body.should.be.property('id').eq('dfarm1');
                         done();                  
                    })
                  .catch((err) => done(err));  
            });
        });
```

API Response

```
 responseSuccessfully registered admin user pc and imported it into the wallet {"secret":"KwCqRJIIwjKx","data":{"type":"X509","mspId":"org1MSP","certificate":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nLHEkr+tge6o=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n","privateKey":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\r\nMIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgbuamIkkqqxjZtIey\r\nn35VYSc8RTaITfVBGY0AflPJp8ShRANCAARmL++OLfzNufy281XBZj5NqiUDqgPm\r\nkbdutoGHtM6G1U8tmxaU/TttpIBrRpeenLPQkMVh6CCtjbGhMaDmNcqh\r\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n"},"httpstatus":200}
```

In above code I am trying to test the put method and sending some userdata which is in json, but I am getting error as "

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 40" 
>   please suggest how can I fix this issue??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... We can't see the data; how could we know?

Comment: sorry to ask you, do you need my API details or just response which is getting from this API?

Comment: just response from the API

Comment: Hi @SivashanmugamKannan the res is to big to mentioned here, so How can I shared with you?

Comment: Share a link by pasting your  response in  https://gist.github.com/

Comment: I have been added to the question Please find there, Please let me know if you need something else

Comment: Seems your API response isn't valid JSON if it is that entire string, so the error is correct.

Comment: Having the same problem right now. Any solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error a while back. Following is an except from my `package.json` to indicate the versions I am using:

```json
...
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
...
```

What I did to fix that was replace `.end()` with `.send()` in the code pertaining to the request.

```
    const resp = await chai.request(app)
      .get('/api/submissions')
-     .end();  // Removed this
+     .send(); // Added this instead
```

That fixed it for me, even though I still cannot make sense of why this error keeps happening.